# How did The Master turn into a snake creature?

Tags: doctor-who, doctor-who-movie

In the Doctor Who movie The Doctor has to transport The Master's remains. These remains then turn into a snake creature which takes over a human body.

Is this common for Galifreyans or Timelords when all of their lives are used up?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Per [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_%28Doctor_Who%29) on the subject;

> In the prologue, the Master (portrayed by Gordon Tipple) was executed
>   by the Daleks as a punishment for his "evil crimes". **The Master
>   survived his execution by taking on the form of a small, snake-like
>   entity. This entity escaped and slithered inside the Doctor's TARDIS
>   console, forcing the vessel to crash land in San Francisco.**
>
> The novelisation of the television movie by Gary Russell posits that
>   the modifications and alterations that the Master has made to his body
>   over the years in attempts to extend his lifespan had allowed this
>   continued existence, and the implication is that the "[morphant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Doctor_Who_universe_creatures_and_aliens_%28H%E2%80%93P%29#Morphant)"
>   creature is actually another lifeform that the Master's consciousness
>   possesses.

This interpretation is made explicit in the first of the
Eighth Doctor Adventures novels, "[The Eight Doctors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Eight_Doctors)" by Terrance Dicks

> 'How does it work?' asked the Master
>   eagerly.
>
> **'You swallow the deathworm before you go into danger. It
>   becomes dormant and lives inside your body. If you are killed it
>   absorbs your essence, body and spirit. It lives on in your remains -
>   in the ashes even, if the body is burned.**
>
> **As soon as it can, it seeks
>   a new host. It takes over the host and then it dies, but you live
>   again in a new body!'**   Eyes gleaming, the Master picked up the clay
>   pot and clasped it to him.

This was also used in the Doctor Who Magazine comic strip story "The Fallen"
(DWM #273-#276), which states that the morphant was a shape-shifting animal native to Skaro.

[image]